# How to unnest multiple list columns of a dataframe in one go with dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following tibble, which has two nested columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(a = list(c("a", "b"), "c"), b = list(c("1", "2", 
"3"), "3"), c = c(11, 22)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a         b             c
  <list>    <list>    <dbl>
1 <chr [2]> <chr [3]>    11
2 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>    22
```

How can I unnest them at once producing one single tibble?

I tried this but fail:

```
> df %>% unnest(a, b)
Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's probably a cleaner way to do it, but if you want the cartesian product for the columns you can unnest them in sequence, if nothing else:

```
> df %>% 
    unnest(a, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
    unnest(b, .drop = FALSE)

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#       c a     b    
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1    11 a     1    
# 2    11 a     2    
# 3    11 a     3    
# 4    11 b     1    
# 5    11 b     2    
# 6    11 b     3    
# 7    22 c     3
```

Comment: How to write general function (without pipes) for many columns?

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Use `unnest_cross()` (and be careful if list-cols are missing data --> `keep_empty = TRUE`):

```r
unnest_cross <- function(data, cols, ...) {
    .df_out <- data
    .cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(rlang::enquo(cols), data)
    purrr::walk(
        .cols,
        function(col) {
            .df_out <<- unnest(.df_out, {{ col }}, ...)
        }
    )
    .df_out
}
```

## Background: Multiple list-columns with `unnest()`

`unnest` has handled multiple columns since `v0.3.0` (2015). It currently uses the `cols` argument, which accepts typical tidyverse selection methods.

**Note** that it's specifically designed to reverse `nest()`ed data.frames and requires list columns to be "parallel entries ... of compatible sizes". This means:

1. It doesn't work with the OP's data.frame.

```r
df <- structure(list(
    a = list(c("a", "b"), "c"),
    b = list(c("1", "2", "3"), "3"),
    c = c(11, 22)),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

tidyr::unnest(df, cols = tidyselect::everything())
#> Error in `fn()`:
#> ! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 3.
```

2. It will not produce the same output as sequential list-column `unnest()`ing (e.g. a cartesian product).

```r
# "parallel"/"compatible" data.frame
df_parallel <- structure(list(
    a = list(c("a", "b", "c"), "c"),
    b = list(c("1", "2", "3"), "3"),
    c = c(11, 22)),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

tidyr::unnest(df_parallel, cols = tidyselect::everything())
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   a     b         c
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a     1        11
#> 2 b     2        11
#> 3 c     3        11
#> 4 c     3        22
```

## `unnest_cross()` Details

`unnest_cross()` uses `purrr::walk()` to cycle through the specified columns and `unnest()` them, saving the result each time via superassignment (with `<<-`). It's name is derived from similarity to `purrr::cross()` because it always produces a cartesian product of list columns in a data.frame, *even* when they are "parallel entries" and/or "of compatible sizes"

1. It works as desired for the original data.frame (with list-columns of unequal length):

```r
# For original data.frame
unnest_cross(df, cols = tidyselect::everything())
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   a     b         c
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a     1        11
#> 2 a     2        11
#> 3 a     3        11
#> 4 b     1        11
#> 5 b     2        11
#> 6 b     3        11
#> 7 c     3        22
```

2. It creates the cartesian product of `df_parallel`, which is very different from `unnest()` .

```r
# For df with list-columns of "compatible size"
unnest_cross(df_parallel, cols = tidyselect::everything())
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    a     b         c
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 a     1        11
#>  2 a     2        11
#>  3 a     3        11
#>  4 b     1        11
#>  5 b     2        11
#>  6 b     3        11
#>  7 c     1        11
#>  8 c     2        11
#>  9 c     3        11
#> 10 c     3        22
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>